# get all value from table based on other table

Tags: php, mysql

user will select the radio button for each question. value : yes = 1 , no = 0

i already get the solution id from this code :

$query = "SELECT solutionid FROM rule WHERE Q1='$ptptn' AND Q2='$parent' AND Q3='$house'";

---

table rule

```
id | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |solution_id

1  |  1 |  1 |  1 | 1
2  |  0 |  0 |  1 | 2
3  |  1 |  0 |  0 | 3
```

---

table solution

```
id |  S1  |  S2  | S3 

1  |  0.1 |  0.1 |  0.1
2  |  0.5 |  0.5 |  0.1
3  |  0.1 |  0.5 |  0.5
```

---

how i want to code for get all the value (S1,S2,S3) in table solution based on solution_id = id in table rule ?

for example output :

user select all the question and result display rule 1 .

solution : 0.1 , 0.1 , 0.1

tqvm for helping ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about with one query? Using JOINS:

```
SELECT tb1.s1, tb1.s2, tb1.s3

    FROM solution AS tb1
    INNER JOIN rule AS tb2

    ON tb1.id = tb2.solution_id

    WHERE tb2.q1 = '$ptptn'
    AND tb2.q2 = '$parent'
    AND tb2.q3 = '$house';
```

Or, using the solution_id as a variable in your PHP code and put in another query. Assuming you have fetched your query in $row variable, so you have now $row['solution_id'];

```
$query = "SELECT s1, s2, s3 FROM solution WHERE id = $row['solution_id'];";
```

Comment: tqvm .. i get my value ... and one more question .. if i want to do a calculation .. if user enter at texbox 2000 . how i want to calculate one by one for each value i get from databse . for example : Question 1= 2000(user keyin)*0.1(get from database) Question2= 2000*0.05(get from database)..

Comment: `($row['q1'] * 0.1)` -> the var key from the fetched result multiplied by the desired number